# Excel Generating Unique Values Across Multiple

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a project that will ultimately have over 100 sheets within the same workbook and am trying to figure out a method to generate a unique list of values across all of the sheets into another sheet.It is preferred I maintain all of the sheets so the data will be much easier to organize in the future.

The row count fluctuates from sheet to sheet while the type of text strings and the order of the columns remains the same. For example, on sheet 1 column A has the text 'red', column 2 has the text 'visual/foveal/target' and column C has 'Nontarget3'. Then in A45 and B45 the text strings are the same as A1:B1 but C1 is now 'Nontarget16'

The same variation can be possible with the different entry being column B instead of the Col A and C (which now have the same entries). In summary, I am interested in generating a list of all unique groups of cells within adjacent columns for all the rows in each sheet and throughout the workbook. Does the StackOverflow community recommend any courses of action I can explore to try and figure this out?

Comment: Create a scripting dictionary object (eg. "dict") and loop over the sheets, and over the rows in each sheet, concatenating the values in columns A, B and C for each row into a "key" (e.g. by joining with a Chr(0)/vbNull character.  For each of these, check  `dict.Exists(theKey)` and add it if not found.  Finally dump all of the keys from the dictionary onto your summary sheet.